# UIButton.titleLabel shadow is clipping

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uilabel, frame

Because UIButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset property makes the shadow sharp, I changed drawTextInRect method to create custom shadow with radius like below:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
float colorValues[] = {0, 0, 0, opacity};
CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, colorValues);
CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(offsetX, offsetY);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor (context, shadowOffset, radius, shadowColor);
```

This works fine. It creates shadow. I changed bounds of titleLabel and called drawTextInRect method like:

```
button.titleLabel.bounds = CGRectMake(button.titleLabel.bounds.origin.x, button.titleLabel.bounds.origin.y, button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width, button.titleLabel.bounds.size.height);
[button.titleLabel drawTextInRect:button.titleLabel.bounds];
[button setNeedsLayout];
```

Because of titleLabel bounds, the shadow is clipping.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the same with layers. I think it'll sort your issue and probably, you don't require what you did.

Simply, make the layer(CALayer) object of your button and use property whatever you need.Remember, for using layer you need QuartzCore framework to import.

Try it, and in any concern just give a shout-over me.